# Connecting an external hard drive to my MacBook Air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive

How do I connect an external hard drive to my MacBook Air? And once it is connected, how do I find it to see what is on my external hard drive? Very new to Apple products.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect external Hard Disk Drive to any of the USB ports using standard cable.

[image]

As soon as you connect it, HDD's icon shall appear on your desktop automatically.

Comment: You can also connect external hard drives to the Thunderbolt port if the device has a Thunderbolt cable or you have an adapter.

Answer (score 1):

In Finder Preferences, there is a way to show/hide certain items on the desktop. If you plug in your hard disk and you *don't* see it, try changing these options.

[image: Finder Preferences]